# C# creating a fixed size hashtable

Tags: c#, size, hashtable, hash, fixed

I want to be able to create a fixed size hashmap of say 100 buckets, and if I need to store over 100 items then collisions and overwriting will just have to happen. The hashtable class has a IsFixedSize property however it is readonly.

Am I thinking about this completely wrongly, or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Why do you need your hashmap to only have 100 buckets?

Comment: In my application I have a very large amount of possible inputs, lets say for example I have 100000 possible inputs. However, in this application it's likely that only ~5% of those possible inputs will be seen. I want to use the hashmap to compress my input space to a fixed memory size.

Comment: Interestingly, in the base implementation of HashTable, IsFixedSize simply returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections in the .NET framework don't allow for a lot of fine-tuning. Although you might find one efficient enough for your needs. Try some viable ones out before optimizing.

If you don't roll your own then you might find a 3rd party alternative that has more fine-grained controls. For example, see [The C5 Generic Collection Library
for C# and CLI](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) as a possible start. Check into the [various Hash* classes on their documentation page](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/frames.htm).

If you decide to roll your own then you'll want to implement [some of the standard interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(VS.80).aspx) for collections and/or lists, enumerations, etc so they work as expected with C# `foreach` and language and .NET features.

You might also take an efficient C++ implementation if you have one and there are ways of using it in C#/.NET. It might take a bit of finagling but there are answers on SO about how to accomplish this kind of thing.